# Matlab array multiplication after linear indexing

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, sum, multiplication

I have 2 matrices defined as follows:

```
A=[1 2;3 4]   
B=[1 4; 5 3]
```

Then I define `Aensem`, `Bensem` and `Gensem` like this:

```
Arow=A(:);     
Brow=B(:);

Aensem=repmat(Arow,1,10);    
Bensem=repmat(Brow,1,10);

G=A*B;
Grow=G(:);
Gensem=repmat(Grow,1,10);
```

I need to create a function that can calculate any `Gensem`-like arrays directly from `Aensem` and `Bensem`. I only have knowledge of `Aensem` and `Bensem`. I tried the following method, but it's not working:

```
function ret = mat_mult(v1, v2, r)
    ret = zeros(size(v1)); 
    for i = 1:2*r.c.M
        for j = 1:2*r.c.M
            sum = 0;
            for k = 1:2*r.c.M
                sum = sum + ...
                    v1(idx1(i,k,r),:) .* v2(idx1(k,j,r),:);
                ret(idx1(i,j,r),:)=sum;
            end
        end
    end            
end
```

Comment: What is the function of `mat_mult`? You defined it, but never used it.

Comment: "not working" is not a valid problem statement for SO. Please specify what is wrong: does the computation result in a wrong value? Do you get an error? Does it work for some inputs and doesn't work for others? Does your computer catch fire when you run the code?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to calculate `Gensem` directly from `Aensem` and `Bensem`. This can be done as follows:

```
A_ = reshape(Aensem(:, 1), 2, 2); % extract A from Aensem
B_ = reshape(Bensem(:, 1), 2, 2); % extract B from Bensem
G_ = A_*B_; % calculate G based on the extracted A and B
Gensem_ = repmat(G_(:),1,10); % build Gensem
```